# Tag Model in a mvc form

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, web

I've got a form that has a dropDownlist using the Model to fill the list, the view is rendered. The issue is that when i press the submit button, a null pointer exception for Model is thrown. I want to receive the value selected in the Post Action.

Here is my code:

**Model:**

```
public class BillViewModel
{
    public List<SelectListItem> ClientList { get; set; }
    public int SelectedClient { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var billRepo = new BillRepo();
    var bill = new BillViewModel {ListProducts = billRepo.GetAllProducts()};
    bill.ClientList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    List<Client> allClientList = billRepo.GetAllClients();

    foreach (Client client in allClientList)
    {
        var item = new SelectListItem() { Value = client.ClientId.ToString(), Text = client.Name };
        bill.ClientList.Add(item);
    }

    ViewBag.ClientSelect = new SelectList(billRepo.GetAllClients(), "value", "text", bill.SelectedClient);

    bill.SelectedClient = 1;
    return View(bill);
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(BillViewModel billViewModel)
{
     return View();
}
```

**View: The Model**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
     @Html.DropDownListFor(item => item.SelectedClient, Model.ClientList, "Select Client")
     <input type="submit" value="Aceptar"/>
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your POST action you are returning the same Index view as in your GET action. But you are not passing any model to this view. That's why you are getting a NRE. Your view must render a dropdown and you need to populate its values, the same way you did in your GET action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(BillViewModel billViewModel)
{
    bill.ClientList = billRepo
        .GetAllClients()
        .ToList()
        .Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = client.ClientId.ToString(), 
            Text = client.Name
        })
        .ToList();

    return View(billViewModel);
}
```

Notice how the view model is passed to the view and how the `ClientList` property (to which your dropdown is bound) is filed with values.